# Type '(_event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLUListElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I have a component **"PageFooter"** which duplicated three times in other components and I try to make it like UI component.

"
Type '(_event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1375, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PaginationProps & RefAttributes'
"

Error line

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

I have this error which I don't know how to fix. Can someone help me?

The code

```
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward';
import {
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationRenderItemParams,
  Switch,
} from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface Props {
  page: number;
  lastPage: number;
  tickActive?: boolean;
  setTickActive: (event: boolean) => void;
  setPage: (value: number) => void;
}

const PageFooter: React.FC<Props> = ({
  page,
  lastPage,
  tickActive,
  setTickActive,
  setPage,
}) => {
  const handleChange = (_event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: number) => {
    setPage(value);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingTop: 4,
        }}
      >
        <Box
          sx={(theme) => ({
            color: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black',
            borderRadius: '6px',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            fontFamily: 'Brandon Grotesque Bold',
            fontSize: '13px',
          })}
        >
          Showing page {page} of {lastPage || 1}
        </Box>
        <Pagination
          count={lastPage}
          color="primary"
          page={page}
          renderItem={(item: PaginationRenderItemParams) => (
            <PaginationItem
              components={{
                previous: ArrowBackIcon,
                next: ArrowForwardIcon,
              }}
              {...item}
            />
          )}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>
        <Box sx={{ mt: 6 }}>
          Tick is active
          <Switch
            checked={tickActive}
            onChange={(event) => setTickActive(event.target.checked)}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default PageFooter;
```

I tried to find answer but I don't take need me decision

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have incorrectly typed the parameters of your `handleChange` method.

You have typed it as:

`(_event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: number)`

But if we look at the Material UI documentation (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination/) for the Pagination component, we can see that the type should be:

`(event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, page: number)`

Change `React.SyntheticEvent` to `React.ChangeEvent`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me. In other components this problem hasn't been, but when I tried to make PageFooter like UI component I get this error

Comment: Is the error exactly the same or different?

Comment: When I changed React.SyntheticEvent to React.ChangeEvent the error exactly the same